# Did the psalmist taunt God in Psalm 44:23?

Tags: psalms, 1-kings

> NIV 1 Kings 18:27
> At noon Elijah began to **taunt** them. "Shout louder!" he said. "Surely he is a god! Perhaps he is deep in thought, or busy, or traveling. Maybe he is **sleeping** and must be awakened."

> Psalm 44:23
> Awake, Lord! Why do you **sleep**? Rouse yourself! Do not reject us forever.

What was the psalmist attitude when he wrote this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The psalmist doe NOT taunt God.  However, as humans we are often frustrated by God's **apparent** lack of action.  That is, human language is used to talk to God and express human fears and hopes.

- Ps 13:1 - How long, LORD? Will you forget me forever? How long will you hide your face from me?
- Ps 94:3 - How long, LORD, will the wicked, how long will the wicked be jubilant?
- Hab 1:2 - How long, LORD, must I call for help, but you do not listen? Or cry out to you, "Violence!" but you do not save?
- Ps 89:46 - How long, LORD? Will you hide yourself forever? How long will your wrath burn like fire?
- Ps 35:17 - How long, O Lord, will You look on? Rescue my soul from their ravages, my precious life from these lions.
- Ps 79:5 - How long, O LORD? Will You be angry forever? Will Your jealousy burn like fire?
- Ps 6:3 - My soul is deeply distressed. How long, O LORD, how long?
- Ps 80:4 - O LORD God of Hosts, how long will Your anger smolder against the prayers of Your people?

Ps 44:23 is in keeping with the impatient cry of sinners for God to act.  Unfortunately, this psalm also recognizes that the calamities have come upon them because of their unfaithfulness (V9-12), and that Judah has become a reproach among the surrounding nations (V13-16), because of their stubbornness (V17-19).

In V23-26 the Sons of Korah encourage God to rise up and act to redeem the people.  This is a simple pea to God to (effectively) forgive wickedness and restore their fortunes, despite their unfaithfulness.

The Cambridge commentary has this:

> 23. Awake … arise] Bestir thyself … awake. Cp. Psalm 7:6, and many similar invocations. But nowhere else do we find so bold an
>     expostulation as why sleepest thou? The nearest parallel is in Psalm
>     78:65. The Psalmists do not shrink from using human language in
>     reference to God, though they well knew that the Watchman of Israel
>     was one who neither slumbered nor slept (Psalm 121:3-4).
>
> It is recorded in the Talmud that in the time of the high-priest John
> Hyrcanus (b.c. 135–107) certain Levites, called ‘Awakeners,’ daily
> ascended the pulpit in the Temple and cried, “Awake, why sleepest
> thou, O Lord”? He put a stop to the practice, saying, “Does Deity
> sleep? Has not the Scripture said, ‘Behold he that keepeth Israel
> neither slumbereth nor sleepeth?’ ”

The pulpit commentary is also helpful:

> Verses 23-26. - The appeal to God is now made, after the case has been
> fully represented. God has always hitherto maintained the cause of his
> people, and given them victory over their enemies, unless they had
> fallen away from him (vers. 1-8). Now he has acted otherwise - he has
> allowed their enemies to triumph (vers. 9-16). And they have given him
> no reason for his desertion of them (vers. 17-22). Surely, if they
> call upon him, and plead their cause before him, he will relent, and
> come to their aid. The appeal, therefore, is made briefly, but in the
> most moving terms. Verse 23. - Awake, why sleepest thou, O Lord? The
> psalmist does not really believe that Jehovah "sleeps." The heathen
> might so imagine of their gods (1 Kings 18:27), but not an Israelite.
> An Israelite would be sure that "he that keepeth Israel neither
> slumbers nor sleeps" (Psalm 121:4). The writer consciously uses an
> anthropomorphism, really intending only to call on God to rouse
> himself from his inaction, and lay it aside, and come to Israel's aid.
> Arise (see Psalm 7:6; Psalm 9:19; Psalm 10:12, etc.). Cast us not off
> for ever (comp. ver. 9). Under the existing peril, for God to cast off
> his people will be to cast them off for ever. They had no strength of
> their own that could save them.